# How to store order of user input and update string

Tags: matlab, class, object, properties

I am trying to make the field 'all names' display all of the selected 'names' (letters in this case) in the order they have been selected (assumed left-to-right). What I have written seems to only be functional if only the first transformation is applied and for the case A + E/F/G. All the rest do not work and I do not understand why.

[image: All letters on transformation 1 work fine]

The code for the first dropdown is this:

```matlab
% Value changed function: DropDown
        function DropDownValueChanged(app, event)
            app.FirstName = app.DropDown.Value;
            
            switch app.FirstName
                case 'A'
                    app.FinalNameDrop.Value='A';                  
                case 'B'
                    app.FinalNameDrop.Value='B'; 
                case 'C'
                    app.FinalNameDrop.Value='C';   
            end
            
        end
```

I was advised by an internet stranger that I can "define a property on the class itself!" and so I tried

```matlab
properties (Access = private)
        Property % Description
        FirstName
        SecondName
    end
```

However, I am unsure how this can help me. How would I go about making this functional?

[image: Case A-E working]

Comment: Why do you need all of the `switch/case` statements? Can't you just do `app.AllNames.Value = strjoin( {app.DropDown1.Value, app.DropDown2.Value, app.DropDown3.Value}, ' + ' );`? Obviously my variable names are wrong here... If you need to handle the "none" then just check that first and make it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put this in all callback methods:

```
app.dropDownFinal.Value = sprintf('%s + %s + %s',app.dropDown.Value app.dropDown2.Value app.dropDown3.Value);
```

Comment: and only that! delete all those switch statements!